# Selection no longer functions inShutter afetr 20.04.1 upgrade

Tags: upgrade

After upograding to 22.04.1 the function "selection" no longer opens in "Shutter". It is greyed out. A print screen is however possible.
I can not remove shutter as I receive a reply "no packages to remove".
Any suggestions for a novice ?

Comment: please [edit] your question to include how you you are trying to remove `Shutter`. If you use ubuntu software and enter `Shutter` in the search box, does it indicate it is installed? Have you tried using `Synaptic Package Manager` to remove it? You can report an issue to the developer at https://shutter-project.org/contact/ IIRC `shutter was not downloadable directly from ubunt software center in 20.04 versions but from github and required the ppa to be added which may be significant. [see here](https://www.tecmint.com/install-shutter-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: Incidentally, I just tried a newly installed instance of `Shutter` on 22.04 LTS installed from scratch and `Selection` works fine so I think the resolution to your issue is to find a way of removing the upgraded version and re-installing it.

Answer (score 2):

Using [this ubuntu handbook reference](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/nstall-shutter-ubuntu-20-04-official-ppa/) you can remove `Shutter` by taking the following steps:

- You can remove Shutter PPA as well as other PPAs via “Software &
  Updates” utility under “Other Software” tab.
- remove `Shutter` using the command 
  `sudo apt remove --autoremove shutter`

After which it should be possible to install `Shutter` from Ubuntu Software in 22.04 LTS

Comment: +1 I missed Shutter so much in 20.04. I thought the project was abandoned, but Shutter is back in Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answer but I found a "workaround":-
Reboot the computer and on arriving at the request for login click on your name then go down to the little cog in the bottom right of the screen an select Ubuntu on Xorg, then enter your password and shutter is back to normal.