ubuntu 22.04 how to fix shutter -- installed but grayed out
I have ubuntu 22.04 and installed Shutter. When I click on it the application comes up but everything is grayed out except the screeenshot for the entire screen. I don't know what is wrong, so I don't know how to fix it.
When I installed it I used PPA: sudo add-apt-repository PPA:linuxuprising/shutter
Somewhere it mentioned that this has been replaced with a new PPA and perhaps that is the problem. But I don't know what the new PPA is and can't to find it.
Can anyone can give me the proper linux commands to install Shutter, or help some other way?

This might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424659/selection-no-longer-functions-inshutter-afetr-20-04-1-upgrade

Sorry it did not.  It said that uninstalling and installing a new copy worked.  I did that and am back exactly where I was.  Everything is grayed out.

Did you remove your PPA first as it was instructed?

which windowing system are you using? If Wayland, Shutter needs to be re-installed using shutter on wayland

Graham, when I look for the release it says ubuntu 22.04.   I installed the Debian version. Any other thoughts.

Amar-- I was not given instructions to remove my ppa first.  If you can tell me how to do that I'll try again.

you installed the .deb version so follow the instructions. It also tells you how to remove the deb version IIRC towards the end of the article. Ubuntu is Debian based if that is your concern.
